# C++ - Escape sequence doesn't work on my system

Tags: c++, escaping, alarm, sequences

I just started learning C++, and I came across an escape sequence that must make a beep. When I compile it and run, i don't hear a beep for some reason. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "Cool\a\nHey man!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The sequence `\a` doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work means no alert sound?

Comment: Yes Zigma. I don't hear an alert sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of that is working for me.  First off, is your terminal beep working?  That may be hard to test; you could try `printf '\a'` from the command-line.

Also, try running the output through a hex dump tool; either of these should do the trick:

```
xxd
od -tx1
```

Verify the bell is coming out as a character with value 7.

Comment: After I tried the C++ code after I run both commands in hexdump, it still didn't work. Maybe there is something else you know?

Comment: Did the hexdump show the expected output?  If so, the problem isn't the program, but the terminal.  Some terminals can turn off the bell.  And some terminals do not have a bell.

Comment: It did show some output, so I think they work, and the problem is that the terminal doesn't have a bell. Thanks for all your help!